# bootstrap image thumbnails ribbon on the left stacks over image on the right on narrow screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am creating image viewer.

It's layout is as follows http://bootply.com/85916

on the left (red background) are image thumbnails stacked vertically (span2 with min-width)
on the right (green background) is the image (span10)

Th problem is that on 1024 pixel screen width image stacks below thumbnails.

I think I need some tweak, or even use plain layout without bootstrap but don't know how.

For now I just change span10 to span9 with javascript if window size is less than 1175

Comment: What is the question? Can you please explain further?

Comment: How to make right part not stack under left part